# Resin server error

Tags: java, resin

Hi I get this error in windows xp, when try to access http://localhost:8080.  I do not see any errors in resin before hand.  Also the JAVA_HOME in windows is set.

500 Servlet Exception

Resin can't load com.sun.tools.javac.Main.  Usually this means that the
JDK tools.jar is missing from the classpath, possibly because of using
a JRE instead of the JDK.  You can either add tools.jar to the classpath
or change the compiler to an external one with 
or jikes.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.Main in NonScanDynamicClassLoader[JarLoader[[]]]

Thanks

P P

Answer (score 1):

I've copied tools.jar into resin's lib folder and all has solved

Answer (score 1):

Resin can be configured to use an external compiler for JSPs instead of the internal one using tools.jar. Invoking an external compiler is slower but might be the easier configuration in some cases.

To change this you have to edit `conf/resin.conf` and change the following setting from `internal` to `javac`.

```
<!--
   - You can change the compiler to "javac" or jikes.
   - The default is "internal" only because it's the most
   - likely to be available.
  -->
<javac compiler="javac" args=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resin can't load com.sun.tools.javac.Main. Usually this means that the JDK tools.jar is missing from the classpath, possibly because of using a JRE instead of the JDK. You can either add tools.jar to the classpath or change the compiler to an external one with or jikes.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.Main in NonScanDynamicClassLoader[JarLoader[[]]]

---

i came across the same issue but i eventually succeeded fixing it by the following steps below:::::

1-  is inside conf/resin.conf

2- your system path should completely include the path to javac compiler in accordance with jdk directory.

3-Run java -jar resin-3.*.*/lib/resin.jar again

4-http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

> Usually this means that the JDK tools.jar is missing from the classpath, possibly because of using a JRE instead of the JDK.

Ok, so is your `JAVA_HOME` pointing to a JRE or a JDK?

Comment: and are you sure that resin looks at JAVA_HOME?

Comment: thats what the installation guide said

Comment: so I switched over to resin 3.19 from 4.0 and modified a java complier tag to be javac and put an env variable for RESIN_HOME and it worked,  version 4.0 is strange that it does not have resin.conf in it.